# Changing the date in Countdown

Tags: countdown

How can I change the date from my countdown?
I know it is working but can't find the place to change the date!
I'm a newby, sorry for asking!

(function($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function(options, callback) {

```
    //custom 'this' selector
    thisEl = $(this);

    //array of custom settings
    var settings = { 
        'date': null,
        'format': null
    };

    //append the settings array to options
    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    //main countdown function
    function countdown_proc() {

        eventDate = Date.parse(settings['date']) / 1000;
        currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);

        if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
            callback.call(this);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        seconds = eventDate - currentDate;

        days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
        seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed

        hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed

        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed

        //conditional Ss
        if (days == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("day"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefDays").text("days"); }
        if (hours == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hour"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefHours").text("hours"); }
        if (minutes == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minute"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefMinutes").text("minutes"); }
        if (seconds == 1) { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("second"); } else { thisEl.find(".timeRefSeconds").text("seconds"); }

        //logic for the two_digits ON setting
        if(settings['format'] == "on") {
            days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
            hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
            minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
            seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
        }

        //update the countdown's html values.
        if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
            thisEl.find(".days").text(days);
            thisEl.find(".hours").text(hours);
            thisEl.find(".minutes").text(minutes);
            thisEl.find(".seconds").text(seconds);
        } else { 
            alert("Invalid date. Here's an example: 12 Tuesday 2012 17:30:00");
            clearInterval(interval); 
        }
    }

    //run the function
    countdown_proc();

    //loop the function
    interval = setInterval(countdown_proc, 1000);

}
```

}) (jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

Look for a separate code, or add these lines. Change function/variable/date accordingly

```
/** Countdown Timer **/

$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $("#countdown").countdown({
        date: "20 sep 2020 12:00:00", /** Enter new date here **/
        format: "on"
    },
    function() {
        // callback function
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What you provided looks to be the function (the engine) and the code you're looking for calls this. I think you'll find what you are looking for is a line that says something like:

```
$.fn.countdown({ 
    'date': 'PLACE DATE HERE',
    'format': null
}, function(){
    //Some code here
);
```

The values may be slightly different but it'll be something like that. When you call that function, you provide the date to work off of.